# Typerror in machine learning tutorial, numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter

This is the notebook that's giving me a problem: https://github.com/justmarkham/scikit-learn-videos/blob/master/07_cross_validation.ipynb

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(25, n_folds=5, shuffle=False)

# print the contents of each training and testing set
print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 'Training set observations',             
'Testing set observations'))
for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
    print('{:^9} {} {:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```

This is the error I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

I don't really know where to start because I'm not that familiar with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's just missing the explicit string conversion:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
kf = KFold(25, n_folds=5, shuffle=False)

# print the contents of each training and testing set
print('{} {:^61} {}'.format('Iteration', 
                            'Training set observations', 
                            'Testing set observations'))
for iteration, data in enumerate(kf, start=1):
    print('{:^9} {} {:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], str(data[1])))
```

or:

```
    print('{:^9} {} {!s:^25}'.format(iteration, data[0], data[1]))
```

The `!s` is just another way of converting it to a string.

In general the formatting mini-language is explained in ["Format Specification Mini-Language"](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)